# Android SharedPreferences vulnerabilities

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am developing an application where users can play simple games and earn points with each game. The application consists of starting and ending multiple activities and with each activity, a request is made to update the user information.

There are multiple requests to the server with this back-forward activity template, so I was thinking if I could save the points with SharedPreferences and make a single request at the best time.

My concern is: can someone mod the application and change its SharedPreferences points? Are there any vulnerabilities regarding SharedPreferences? I am afraid to start saving the user points in SharedPreferences and then someone cheats his points with some exploit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there any vulnerabilities regarding SharedPreferences

Yes, if a user has a rooted device they can easily get the shared preferences file and update it.

What you could do is use [EncrypedSharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/topic/security/data) to store the data but a good rule is if you don't want someone to potentially get access to something they shouldn't then you should not keep it on the device

Comment: Can a user with root device update the code itself? Lets say, change a textview value or even a param in a web request?

Comment: not directly, they could theoretically decompile your app and recompile it with changes

Answer (score 1):

To  make it more difficult to extract from the device you can store it inside Keystore system.Once keys are in the keystore, they can be used for cryptographic operations with the key material remaining non-exportable.

For more information about storing on keystore please check below link
https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore